# Dropwizard Hibernate Unable to locate persister Error

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, dropwizard

I have set up a Dropwizard project and my first endpoint for a baseball stats api. The functioning table and class names are rangerstats_player / Player. I tried to do the same for a table I have called rangerstats_hitter_season_stats but I run into the error below when trying to do a simple GET and have not figured out how to fix it or what the problem is

```
org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: core.HitterSeasonStats
```

Below is the code for both classes/tables to show the similarities since I think the pattern is exactly the same and I have no idea what could be wrong.

HitterSeasonStats.java (commented out some fields to try to get it to work in case they might be the problem)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rangerstats_hitter_season_stats") 
public class HitterSeasonStats {
    @Id
    private long id;
//    @Column(name = "player_id")
//    private long playerId;
    private int g;
    private int pa;
    private int ab;
    //private double avg;
    private int h;
    private int single;
    @Column(name = "double")
    private int doubles;
    private int triple;
    private int hr;
    private int rbi;
    private int bb;
    private int k;
    private int hbp;
    private int sf;
//    private double slg;
//    private double obp;
//    private double ops;
//    private double war;
    //@Column(name = "season_year")
    //private Date seasonYear;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

HitterSeasonStatsDAO.java

```
public class HitterSeasonStatsDAO extends AbstractDAO<HitterSeasonStats> {
    public HitterSeasonStatsDAO(SessionFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
    }

    public Optional<HitterSeasonStats> findById(Long id) {
        return Optional.fromNullable(get(id));
    }

    public List<HitterSeasonStats> findByPlayer(Long playerId) {
        Criteria criteria = criteria().add(Restrictions.eq("playerId", playerId));
        return list(criteria);
    }

    public List<HitterSeasonStats> findByPlayerAndYear(Long playerId) {
    Criteria criteria = criteria().add(Restrictions.eq("playerId", playerId));
        return list(criteria);
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rangerstats_player")

@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "core.Player.findAll",
            query = "select p from Player p")

})

public class Player {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    private String position;
    private String team;
    private String bat;
    @Column(name = "throw_hand")
    private String throwHand;
    private String height;
    private int age;
    private int weight;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getfirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getlastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    ......
}
```

PlayerDAO.java

```
public class PlayerDAO extends AbstractDAO<Player> {

    public PlayerDAO(SessionFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
    }

    public Optional<Player> findById(Long id) {
        return Optional.fromNullable(get(id));
    }

    public List<Player> findAll() {
        return list(namedQuery("core.Player.findAll"));
    }
}
```

Tables

```
rangersstats=# \dt
                     List of relations
 Schema |               Name               | Type  |     Owner     
--------+----------------------------------+-------+---------------
 public | rangerstats_hitter_game_record   | table | owner
 public | rangerstats_hitter_season_stats  | table | owner
 public | rangerstats_pitcher_game_record  | table | owner
 public | rangerstats_pitcher_season_stats | table | owner
 public | rangerstats_player               | table | owner
```

EDIT:

I believe I have found what is causing the issue.  It is how I am registering the HibernateBundle.  I have put this together form tutorials and have taken syntax from them.  I see I am only using the Player class in my bundle.  I need to find a new way to hook up the database in the main Application class.

```
 private final HibernateBundle<ApiConfig> hibernatePlayerBundle =
    new HibernateBundle<ApiConfig>(Player.class) {
    @Override
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ApiConfig configuration) {
        return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
    }
};

@Override
public void initialize(final Bootstrap<ApiConfig> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(hibernatePlayerBundle);
}

@Override
public void run(final ApiConfig configuration, final Environment environment) {
    final PlayerDAO playerDAO = new PlayerDAO(hibernatePlayerBundle.getSessionFactory());
    final HitterSeasonStatsDAO hitterSeasonStatsDAO = new HitterSeasonStatsDAO(hibernateHitterSeasonStatsBundle.getSessionFactory());
    environment.jersey().register(new HitterSeasonStatsResource(hitterSeasonStatsDAO));
    environment.jersey().register(new PlayerResource(playerDAO));

}
```

I tried to create and add another bundle with the other class but it looks like we can only have one bundle

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A metric named io.dropwizard.db.ManagedPooledDataSource.hibernate.active already exists
```

EDIT:

I need to passed a comma separated list of classes to the HibernateBundle constructor, problem solved! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not having such problems in the future, use `ScanningHibernateBundle`.

`ScanningHibernateBundle` will scan `core`package and all nested sub packages and add all classes with `@Entity` annotation to the Hibernate `SessionFactory`.

```
private final HibernateBundle<ApiConfig> hibernatePlayerBundle =
    new ScanningHibernateBundle<ApiConfig>("core") {
        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ApiConfig configuration) {
            return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
        }
};
```

Better to use `core.model` package name in place of `core`.